# Why feature crosses may work better than having them as individual features?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, feature-engineering

On [Google ML Crash Course](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/feature-crosses/crossing-one-hot-vectors) it is said the following:

> If we build a feature cross from both these features:
>
> [behavior type X time of day]
>
> then we'll end up with vastly more
>   predictive ability than either feature on its own. For example, if a
>   dog cries (happily) at 5:00 pm when the owner returns from work will
>   likely be a great positive predictor of owner satisfaction. Crying
>   (miserably, perhaps) at 3:00 am when the owner was sleeping soundly
>   will likely be a strong negative predictor of owner satisfaction.

Why cross features is better than having them as individual features?

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessarily cross features. Actually, it is a subset of a general concept, namely, *kernel trick*. Using kernel trick you will be able to find decision boundaries which are more complex than usual hyperplanes which can be found using the linear combination of current feature space. Suppose you have a single feature $x$. By employing that you will be able to make a line as a separator of two classes. If you add $x^2$ alongside $x$ you will be able to have a parabola decision boundary rather than a simple line, which enables you to have a complex decision boundary in cases which is needed. Moreover, because you have both $x$ and $x^2$ you can set the coefficient of each to zero which means you have a kind of flexibility to decide to have a simple line or a parabola.

Comment: Thanks. But they specifically mention cross-features an wanted to compare it with having the individual features. Sorry, can't relate that to your answer. I am missing something obviously.

Comment: What I've mentioned is for $1d$, for higher spaces, for instance a problem with two features, you can have, $x$, $y$, $xy$. you can add the higher order polynomials to them for better interpolation. If you are familiar with numerical calculations, you can approximate any funciton using regressors depending on your kernel. There is also another perspective in signals & systems. You can make any signal using the fourier basis. I can just tell you that in this context, $xy$ is just for showing the kernel trick.